# Rename worksheet to cell value while keeping the format

Tags: vba, date, excel

I am trying to rename a worksheet in VBA. I need to name it like 'yymmdd' for ex.: 150212 should be the name of the worksheet. I have written the below mentioned code but when the code tries to rename the worksheet then it does not pick up the value in the format 'yymmdd'. VBA gives me an error that the name cannot contain /. I need a way out so that the name of the worksheet becomes 'yymmdd'.

```
Range("G1").Value = Date
Range("G1").NumberFormat = "yymmdd"
Sheets("Fund Flow").Name = Range("G1").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use `.Text` instead! Adding remove white spaces in front and back.

`Sheets("Fund Flow").Name = Trim(Range("G1").Text)`

Or simply

`Sheets("Fund Flow").Name = Format(Date,"yymmdd")`

Comment: Manya, when an answer works for you, go ahead and accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.